# Mysql search using where clause in same column

Tags: mysql

Hello I'm having a problem.

I want to search values in the name column using the where clause. Example table is this with values stored.

```
table1
--------------------------
id  | name   | anotherid
--------------------------
1   | name1  | 1
2   | name2  | 1
2   | name2  | 2
```

I have textboxes that I can change how many they appear. For example I have two textboxes. The value on textbox one is 'name1' and the second is 'name2'

My query must find those two values in table1 and, when they're found, their anotherid column must be the same also.

From the first table, All I want to get is this:

```
table1
--------------------------
id  | name   | anotherid
--------------------------
1   | name1  | 1
2   | name2  | 1
```

However when a situation like this appears and I still have two textboxes with the same values:

```
table1
--------------------------
id  | name   | anotherid
--------------------------
1   | name1  | 1
2   | name2  | 1
2   | name2  | 2
3   | name3  | 1
```

The result must be empty.

Now back to the first table. I used this code.

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE name = "name1" and name = "name2"
and
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE name = "name1" and name = "name2" group by anotherid
```

but all I get are empty results.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in you `WHERE` clause,

`WHERE name = "name1" and name = "name2"` will always return false. Use **OR** instead.

Try any of these:

**1.** Selecting with `name1`,`name2` and `anotherid=1`

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE (name="name1" OR name="name2") 
AND anotherid=1
```

The result will be:

```
id   name    anotherid  
1    name1   1
2    name2   1
```

**2.** Grouping by `anotherid`:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
GROUP BY anotherid
```

Result:

```
ID  NAME    ANOTHERID
1   name1   1
2   name2   2
```

**3.** Grouping by `name`:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
GROUP BY name
```

Result:

```
ID  NAME    ANOTHERID
1   name1   1
2   name2   1
```

Comment: Sorry. I edited my question. you cannot have anotherid be an input.

Comment: Then what you mean by `GROUP BY anotherid`, my friend?

Comment: I was confused when the first line didn't work so I tried many things. I'm kind of new in this.

Comment: @user3436844: Edited my answer. Pick what kind of result you are looking for.

Comment: #1 is good but anotherid isn't an input
#2 - #3 I edited my question again to give more information

Comment: @user3436844: You can replace the `GROUP BY` clause in #1 with `GROUP BY` clauses in #2 or #3 and see you get your result. If not, let me know.

Comment: #3 - SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE (name = "name1" or name = "name2") group by name

Definitely works. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE name = "name1" OR name = "name2"  group by anotherid
```

That should do.

Comment: Sorry. I edited my question. you cannot have anotherid be an input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` group by name
```